# Load times for files in pub/static/ are extremely variable and often painfully slow

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, performance

On Magento 2.3.3 I'm seeing extremely variable load times for files served from Magento's `pub/static` directory. This happens in both developer and production modes, and I can't understand what's causing it.

Main symptoms are pages which take a huge amount of time to load, especially on first visit and especially when the FPC is disabled. But I don't just mean "a few seconds extra" - I'm talking **minutes** of load time.

`pub/static` resources (mainly JS files) take several seconds each to reach TTFB i.e. there's tons of "waiting" for files in the browser. This causes a massive amount of request blocking as the browser waits.

Even if I load up the URI of a single JS file in the browser the load times are insanely variable: first time I request a file directly it might take 4 seconds to load, then I refresh a couple of times and it loads instantly, then I refresh again and it's back to 4-5 seconds. And this is on a machine which has zero net traffic other than my own testing.

The hardware I'm using is a 32-core CentOS-based machine with 128GB RAM and SSDs so this should not be a hardware issue. I'm running httpd, MariaDB, php-fpm, redis/memcache for page cache and session storage. I've set up Varnish in the past but would prefer to get Magento running acceptably *before* resorting to using aggressive caching as a crutch.

My php-fpm config looks like this:

```
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/website.sock
listen.owner = magento
listen.group = www
listen.mode = 0660
user = magento
group = www
pm = static
pm.max_children = 500
pm.start_servers = 30
pm.min_spare_servers = 30
pm.max_spare_servers = 50
pm.max_requests = 500
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
php_admin_flag[zlib.output_compression] = On
php_value[memory_limit] = "4096M"
php_value[session.gc_maxlifetime] = "86400"
php_value[opcache.memory_consumption] = 512MB
php_value[opcache.max_accelerated_files] = 60000
php_value[opcache.consistency_checks] = 0
php_value[opcache.revalidate_freq] = 0
php_value[opcache.enable_cli] = 1
php_value[opcache.interned_strings_buffer] = 64
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check anything wrong with redis? I have a similar problem in my dev setup. When I changed the cache from redis to files, again site went faster.. Not a server expert to debug on these issues so I left it there, and still using file cache/session for my dev setup